# Are there any Christograms that were used by Early Christians but are no more in use?

Tags: church-history, art

Christogram (Latin: Monogramma Christi) is a monogram or combination of letters that forms an abbreviation for the name of Jesus Christ, traditionally used as a religious symbol within the Church. As of today, two Christograms namely Chi Rho (XP) and IHS are in use, the former having an artistic look and the latter, a plain look. There is however, an intertwined version of IHS seen in some ancient churches like St Martin's in Northern France.

My question is: **Are there other Christograms that were used by early Christians but are no more in use?**

Answer (score 2):

I have seen the IX monogram (I for Iesous/Ιησους, X for Christos/Χριστος) on early Christian Roman sarcophagi in Ravenna and on early Byzantine sculptures. In a web search, I've also found Merovingian sarcophagi depicting it. I can't recall ever seeing it on more recent artwork, so I suppose it might have fallen into disuse in the early Middle Ages (please correct me if I'm mistaken).

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259). I would also recommend reading the [Help Center's](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) sections on asking and answering questions.

Comment: Could you possibly add a link to support your claim.

Answer (score 2):

**Are there Christograms that were used by early Christians but are no more in use?**

The short answer is **no**.

True that some are quite hard to find and are almost obsolete, but they are still to be found on modern times.

Even the [IX monogram](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IX_monogram) (I for Iesous/Ιησους, X for Christos/Χριστος) can be found occasionally.

[image]

[IX Christogram](https://www.adcrucem.com/products/ad-crucem-christmon-ix-christogram)